# Add days to html form date picker

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

So what am i doing wrong here?
I have a form with 2 date html datepickers, 1 is for when they arrive where the date is min today, the other one im trying to do so they can only book min of 1 week.

If you guys have any idea how to do it easier please tell me that would help me a lot!

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="booking.js"></script> -->

<script type="text/javascript">
        var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
document.getElementsByName("a_Date")[0].setAttribute('min', today);

    var vDate = (today).getDate(today);
    console.log(vDate);
    console.log(today);


        document.getElementsByName("v_Date")[0].setAttribute('min', vDate); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I clearly understood what you want to achieve here, you must to restrict an amount of days between two dates. In this case, 1 week.
There are some requirements beside this, for example, you want to initiate the first datepicker element from today as the minimum date.

I made this example to you, then you can just fit to your elements.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker({
          minDate: 0, 
          onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            var newDate = new Date(selectedDate);
            newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 7)
            $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", newDate);
          }
        });
        $( "#to" ).datepicker();
    
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <label for="from">From</label>
    <input type="text" id="from" name="from">
    <label for="to">to</label>
    <input type="text" id="to" name="to"> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, i think that will work out! is there also a that they can only book per week so 7days , 14days and so on. instead of 8, 10?

Comment: Dear Ryan, all you gotta do is to alter setting of the newDate variable. Notice that I used newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 7), but you can set for the time you want.